# merge cells and apply style phpexel

Tags: php, phpexcel

When doing merge cells and applying style in loop script is giving fatal error mentioned below.

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\xampp\htdocs\bookings\vendor\phpoffice\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 892

NOTE: but if we use it out side the loop it works fine, My code which i use to apply style and merge the cell is as below.

```
$range = chr($alpha).'1:'.chr($alpha+1).'1';
$spreadsheetWriter->mergeCell($range);
$spreadsheetWriter->setCellStyle($range);
```

What is wrong here, or is there any way which i can use to handle fatal error.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Always try to apply styles outside of a loop where possible..... and for a merge range, just apply the style to the top-left cell of the merge range

Comment: Incidentally, why aren't you actually specifying any style to set?

Comment: @MarkBaker actually setCellStyle is a function of my class, which sets font weight to bold, and cell alignment to center.

Comment: Then it might be useful to see some of the logic of your wrapper class